# validating month and year with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, date

I have a function that takes the month and year and checks to see if it is in the past. It is working except for when you pick a two digit month, like 11/2013. It thinks that it is in the past.

How do I get dates like 10/2013 to validate?

```
creditDate = function(){
now = new Date();
month = now.getUTCMonth();
year = now.getUTCFullYear();
current = month + "/" + year;
selectedMonth = $('#ctl00_MainContentHolder_Payment1_CreditCardInput1_ExpMonthField')
yourMonth = selectedMonth.val();
selectedYear = $('#ctl00_MainContentHolder_Payment1_CreditCardInput1_ExpYearField')
yourYear = selectedYear.val();
yourDate = yourMonth + "/" + yourYear
if (yourDate < current){
    selectedMonth.css('background-color', 'pink');
    selectedYear.css('background-color', 'pink');
    $('#errorAlertTwo').append('Credit card expiration date is invalid.' + '<br>');
    return false;
        } else {
        return true;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do it on a year, month basis

```
if (yourYear < currentYear || (yourYear == currentYear && yourMonth < currentMonth)) {
    selectedMonth.css('background-color', 'pink');
    selectedYear.css('background-color', 'pink');
    $('#errorAlertTwo').append('Credit card expiration date is invalid.' + '<br>');
    return false;
    }
else {
    return true;
}
```